# pandas data frame KeyError oop

Tags: python, pandas, oop, ta-lib

The purpose of this script is to read a csv file.

The file contains forex data.

The file has 7 columns Date, Time, Open, High, Low, Close and Volume, and around 600k rows.

After scraping the date and time the script must will make some date time calculation like month and day.

Then some technical analysis using TA-LIB library.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import talib


class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.names = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
        self.open = self.df['Open'].astype(float)
        self.high = self.df['High'].astype(float)
        self.low = self.df['Low'].astype(float)
        self.close = self.df['Close'].astype(float)

    def file(self, file):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(file, names=self.names,
                              parse_dates={'Release Date': ['Date', 'Time']})
        return self.df

    def date(self):
        self.df['Release Date'] = pd.to_datetime(self.df['Release Date'])

    def year(self):
        self.df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(self.df['Release Date']).dt.year

    def month(self):
        self.df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(self.df['Release Date']).dt.month

    def day(self):
        self.df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(self.df['Release Date']).dt.day

    def dema(self):
        # DEMA - Double Exponential Moving Average
        self.df['DEMA'] = talib.DEMA(self.close, timeperiod=30)

    def ema(self):
        # EMA - Exponential Moving Average
        self.df['EMA'] = talib.EMA(self.close, timeperiod=30)

    def HT_TRENDLINE(self):
        # HT_TRENDLINE - Hilbert Transform - Instantaneous Trendline
        self.df['HT_TRENDLINE '] = talib.HT_TRENDLINE(self.close)

    def KAMA(self):
        # KAMA - Kaufman Adaptive Moving Average
        self.df['KAMA'] = talib.KAMA(self.close, timeperiod=30)

    def ma(self):
        # MA - Moving average
        self.df['MA'] = talib.MA(self.close, timeperiod=30, matype=0)

    def print(self):
        return print(self.df.head())


x = Data()
x.file(r"D:\Projects\Project Forex\USDJPY.csv")
x.print()
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Sayed\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Open'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Sayed/PycharmProjects/project/Technical Analysis.py", line 55, in <module>
    x = Data()

  File "C:/Users/Sayed/PycharmProjects/project/Technical Analysis.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.open = self.df['Open'].astype(float)

  File "C:\Users\Sayed\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\Users\Sayed\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'Open'
```

Comment: The error suggests that that there's no `Open` column, check your csv.

Comment: there is open column

Comment: @SayedGouda edit your question to list the output of `df.columns`. Your error suggests that the column `Open` doesn't exist. Perhaps there is a case difference?

Comment: What does `pd.read_csv(r"D:\Projects\Project Forex\USDJPY.csv").columns` return?

Comment: the very same error

Answer (score 2):

In the `__init__` function you are initializing empty DataFrame without any columns. But 1 line after, you are trying to convert `Open` column of the DataFrame to float.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.df = pd.DataFrame() # No columns
    self.names = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
    self.open = self.df['Open'].astype(float) # ERROR: 'Open' column does not exist
    self.high = self.df['High'].astype(float)
    self.low = self.df['Low'].astype(float)
    self.close = self.df['Close'].astype(float)
```

---

Change you init function to this and it should work!

```
def __init__(self):
    self.names = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
    self.df = pd.DataFrame(columns=self.names) # Empty dataframe with columns
    self.open = self.df['Open'].astype(float) # Now 'Open' column exists
    self.high = self.df['High'].astype(float)
    self.low = self.df['Low'].astype(float)
    self.close = self.df['Close'].astype(float)
```

Comment: The error in the question is on line `x = Data()`. Are you getting the same error with the change suggested? I have tried running it and it seems to be working